# Generic carrier for iphone app screen shots

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iphone App submission: Status bar and screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803500/iphone-app-submission-status-bar-and-screenshots)

We looked at some app pages in apple store, and found that the screen shots of apps always say "Carrier" instead of the name of any particular carrier - probably to be neutral.

Any way, here is the question, is that something apple does to all screen shots? or I have to modify my screen shots to be that way.

Second question, if that's something apple does, do I need to cut off the top part of my screens to pave the way for them?

Comment: Didn't look too far and found an app called "color texting effects". Its screen shots have at&t printed on status bar. Any way to be on the safe side, we will cut off the status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone simulator shows the generic "Carrier" label.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator doesnt have a carrier, so just take a screenshot of the emulator and you will be fine :)